# PowerShell SFTP Download without Writing Files to Disk

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to use PowerShell to Sync Payroll files stored on SFTP to SharePoint. I have most of the code written, the only thing I can't figure out is if there is a way to avoid temporarily downloading the file to the disk. Given the sensitivity of these files I would rather store the files as a variable not unlike how get-content works so no one on the Jenkins slave would be able to see its content or undelete temp files.

Here is my working code that does download the file:

```
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)
$file = $session.ListDirectory("/") | select -ExpandProperty files | ? {$_.FileType -ne "D"} | select -First 1
$session.GetFiles($file, "c:\temp\$($file.name)", $False, $transferOptions)
$session.Close()
```

Is there something I can use in replacement of the second parameter of WinSCP.Session.GetFiles [C:\temp\$($file.name)] that would allow me to drop the file directly into memory so I can turn around and dump the to SharePoint?

If you were wondering how I would then get it into sharepoint I have used this with get-content without issue:

```
$fileToUpload = get-content c:\temp\test.csv -Encoding Byte
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.Content = $fileToUpload
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.Url = "test.csv"
$Upload = $Folder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Ctx.Load($Upload)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP simply doesn't do it. I had been hoping for a downstream object to take the replcement of a file path but that does not seem to be possible. However I did figure this out. Moving to the posh-ssh module I was able to use the Get-SFTPContent command which allows me to read in the file to memory.

```
install-module posh-ssh
import-module posh-ssh
$Session = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $SFTPHostName -Credential $SFTPcredential
Get-SFTPContent -SessionId $session.SessionId -Path $file.FullName -Encoding unicode -ContentType byte
```

Answer (score 0):

Streaming a context of a remote file is supported since WinSCP 5.18 beta using the [`Session.GetFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfile).

```
$stream = $session.GetFile($file)
```